# How to exactly map a string to enum in java?

Tags: java

I can't tell if the solution to my problem is really easy or more complicated than it looks.
I've searched up some examples for how to use Enumerated types but I can't figure out how to map a string to an enum if the string value is can be arbitrary and was hoping to get more concrete examples from the community about a particular situation.

Say, for example we had two classes `Test` and `Type (Enum)`.

Type looks like:

```
public enum Type {
TYPE1;
TYPE2;
}
```

Within in the Test class, we had a method called `Map`, which would accept a string and Enum, and it's meant to map the string to a enum value.

```
public void map(String str, Type someType){
//map Str to specified someType in the Enumerated type.. how?
}
```

So calling map would look like:

```
map("johnny", Type.type1);
```

where johnny should get mapped to type1.

How would I do this?

EDIT:

I just wanted to say I ended up using a LinkedList with the enumerated type  instead (which I know is probably slower) simply because this was for an homework assignment and I wanted to know if there was a way to use Enum type only instead of using a Hashmap (we haven't learned hashmaps yet).

Comment: Well, I guess there is a mapping logic and a data structure in which you'd store the mappings... If you give more details, it can be helped...

Comment: Are you looking for [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)? You can do `map.put("johnny", Type.type1)` with that...

Comment: Please follow Java naming conventions: method names should start with a lower case letter (`map(...)` instead of `Map(...)`) and enum values should be all upper case (`TYPE1`, etc.).

Comment: Apologies, fixed. Thanks for all the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to answer,

```
public class Mapping {

    enum Type {
        type1,
        type2;
    }

    Map<String, Type> map = new HashMap<>();

    public void Map(String str, Type someType){
      map.put(str, someType);
    }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
       Mapping mapping = new Mapping();
       mapping.Map("johnny", Type.type1);
       System.out.println(mapping.map);
   }
}
```

but notice that you don't need a function as it is a one-liner anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HashMap<String, Type>` if you don't want to allow duplicates. Although Java's enum constants have more functionality than you'd expect... try `Type.valueOf(string)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the generic Map and insert the values into that map.

```
Map<String, Type> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("johnny", Type.type1);
```

Btw, your enum definition is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to add the mapping function to the enum type directly. For example:

```
enum Type {
    type1,
    type2;

    public static Type mapFrom(String s) {
        ...
    }
}
```

and you would use it as follows:

```
Type type1 = Type.mapFrom("johnny");
```

Answer (score 0):

If your string equals to your enum string, you can use `valueOf` method which enum type generated automatically, like

```
    Type test = Type.valueOf("TYPE1")
```

If you have custom string, you can add a field for you enum type. According to [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078H61SCH), enum type allowed to add any field or method. Effective Java provided an elegant solution by implementing a fromString method on an enum type:

```
public enum Type {
    TYPE1("johnny"),
    TYPE2("cathy");

    private String label;

    Type(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return label;
    }

    private static final Map<String, Type> stringToEnum = Stream.of(values()).collect(toMap(Object::toString, e -> e));

    // Returns Type for string, if any
    public static Optional<Type> fromString(String label) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(stringToEnum.get(label));
    }
}
```

You can test by

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Type type1 = Type.valueOf("TYPE1");
        Type type2 = Type.fromString("johnny").orElse(null);
        System.out.println(type1);
        System.out.println(type2);
    }
```